# Tensor (5-dim matrix) in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix, tensor

I have a CSV file that looks like

| time | Col_A | Col_B | Col_C | Col_D | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A1 | B1 | C2 | D6 | 23.43 |
| 124 | A5 | B3 | C7 | D1 | 14.63 |
| 125 | A3 | B2 | C3 | D2 | 343.43 |
| 126 | A2 | B1 | C2 | D6 | 43.43 |
| 127 | A1 | B1 | C7 | D2 | 6.63 |

Now I want to create a 5-dimensional matrix. I think it is called a tensor?

Question 1) Can this tensor be done in Pandas, or is there a better Python library? Do you have a link to an API manual so I can read more?

The dimensions of the tensor will be "time", "Col_A", "Col_B", "Col_C", "Col_D". The cell will contain the scalar "Price".

So I want to be able to set the cell, maybe something like:

```
my_matrix[time=123, Col_A = A1, Col_B = B1, Col_C = C2, Col_D = D6] = 23.43
```

Question 2) So what is the syntax to set a scalar? And how do I read the scalar?

I would also like to sum over dimensions. Say I want to sum like this below. When I write "*" I mean the star is a wildcard.

```
Matrix[time = *, Col_A = A1, Col_B = B1 and B2 and B3, Col_C = *, Col_D = D6 and D2]
```

Question 3) How do I sum over different dimensions? Do I need to for loop? Can I use other operations, such as divisions?

Actually, I want to put several numbers in each cell. Maybe I would like to put "time" and "Price" into each cell. I was thinking about string concatenation "time_Price", but to do a large summation, there will be lot of substring extraction, which might be time consuming? Therefore, I was thinking of creating several identical tensors. One tensor might contain the "Price" in each cell, and another tensor might contain "time" in each cell. So if I want to check the time for a Price, I will use the same coordinates in both tensors.

Question 4) I guess it is faster to use several tensors where each cell contain a single value, instead of using one single tensor containing many variables i.e. long string of concatenated variables? Or is there a better way?

Comment: 5 columns does not make it 5d 'tensor'.  A dataframe is basically 2d, rows and columns.  A cell can contain a list or array, but that makes it a lot more complicated.

Comment: @hpaulj I am envisioning a 5-dimensional cube. Each side is one of the columns. Then I can sum over some indicies: the 4th row in the first dimension, and the 7th row in the 2nd dimension, etc. Are you saying that a 5-dim cube is not a tensor?

Comment: Described that way it could be viewed as a 5d array.  In the numpy world, 'tensor' doesn't have a special meaning.  But as your description shows, as well as the answer, the 5d cube can  be presented as a 2d table - both in a csv and dataframe.

Comment: @hpaulj this is very informative. I thought a 5-dim matrix is the same as a tensor. But it seems you say they are not necessary the same. So what is the difference between a 5d matrix, and a tensor? I heard they are the same?

Comment: In linear algebra a `matrix` is a 2d object.   Math references talk about tensors as a mapping between objects like matrices, so often they will be 3d in nature.  But `tensor` is also used in the sense of having any number of dimensions.  `numpy arrays` are like that,  But `numpy` documentation rarely, if ever, use the term 'tensor'.  `pandas` is built on `numpy`, so its data is often stored in 1d or 2d arrays.  Indices may also be arrays (if not lists).  To confuse things further a common machine learning package, `tensorflow`, calls its objects `tensors`.

Comment: Your price data might be stored in a 5d array, but array indices are simply 0,1,2..., not your `A1, A2, ...`.  So loading the csv as a pandas data frame is alot easier than constructing a 5d array from it.  And pandas has enough 'grouping' tools that you shouldn't need a 5d array to do things like summing matching values.

Comment: @hpaulj so you are basically saying that I dont need to create a 5-dim matrix, which is a tensor. But instead I can use pandas 2-dim matrix just like normal, to handle my 5-dim data. Ok, that clears things up. Conceptually, I can think of my Pandas dataframe as a 5-dim tensor if I want. But when programming, a normal Dataframe, with 5 columns give the same result - and this is much easier to program. Ok, thanx a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a dataframe is already an appropriate structure for your data. To answer your questions I'll use your sample data, indexed by the `Col_*` columns:

```py
# set up df
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [123, 124, 125, 126, 127],
    'Col_A': ['A1', 'A5', 'A3', 'A2', 'A1'],
    'Col_B': ['B1', 'B3', 'B2', 'B1', 'B1'],
    'Col_C': ['C2', 'C7', 'C3', 'C2', 'C7'],
    'Col_D': ['D6', 'D1', 'D2', 'D6', 'D2'],
    'Price': [23.43, 14.63, 343.43, 43.43, 6.63]
})

# set the index to the `Col_*` columns and sort for performance
df = df.set_index(['Col_A','Col_B','Col_C','Col_D']).sort_index()
```

Now we have a dataframe where the `Col_*` values are the indexes
and the `time` and `Price` values are in the "cells".
This is basically the answer to Question 1.

```
                         time   Price
Col_A Col_B Col_C Col_D
A1    B1    C2    D6      123   23.43
            C7    D2      127    6.63
A2    B1    C2    D6      126   43.43
A3    B2    C3    D2      125  343.43
A5    B3    C7    D1      124   14.63
```

For Question 2 you can just use the index to set the "cell" value:

```
df.loc[('A1','B1','C2','D6'), 'Price'] = 55
```

or both "cells" at once:

```
df.loc[('A1','B1','C7','D2'), ['time', 'Price']] = [100, 99]
```

or with a condition:

```
df.loc[(df.index == ('A2','B1','C2','D6')) & (df['time'] == 126), 'Price'] = 44
```

Output:

```
                         time   Price
Col_A Col_B Col_C Col_D
A1    B1    C2    D6      123   55.00
            C7    D2      100   99.00
A2    B1    C2    D6      126   44.00
A3    B2    C3    D2      125  343.43
A5    B3    C7    D1      124   14.63
```

For Question 3, use indexing to access the values you want; with `slice(None)` for the wildcard:

```
df.loc[('A1', ['B1','B2','B3'], slice(None), ['D2','D6'])].sum()
```

Output:

```
time     223.0
Price    154.0
dtype: float64
```

In terms of Question 4, inside the dataframe you can have as many "cell" values as you like. As shown above, you can access the "cell" values individually or together as needed. For example, let's say you wanted address and gender information. Then you could set a few of those values like this:

```
# set an existing entry
df.loc[('A1','B1','C7','D2'), ['Address', 'Gender']] = ['1 Main St', 'male']

# create a new entry with all 4 values
# (time, price, address, gender)
df.loc[('A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4')] = [130, 45.3, 'High St', 'female']

# create a new entry with only 3 of the 4 values
df.loc[('A1', 'B2', 'C3', 'D4'), ['time', 'Price', 'Address']] = [120, 51.4, '4 Brown St']
```

Starting from the original dataframe, this gives:

```
              time   Price     Address  Gender
A1 B1 C2 D6  123.0   23.43         NaN     NaN
      C7 D2  127.0    6.63   1 Main St    male
A2 B1 C2 D6  126.0   43.43         NaN     NaN
A3 B2 C3 D2  125.0  343.43         NaN     NaN
A5 B3 C7 D1  124.0   14.63         NaN     NaN
A4 B4 C4 D4  130.0   45.30     High St  female
A1 B2 C3 D4  120.0   51.40  4 Brown St     NaN
```

Note that for performance reasons, you should use `df = df.sort_index()` after adding new entries.

You can also search this dataframe easily. For example, find all rows with `Price > 50`:

```
df[df['Price'] > 50]
```

Output:

```
              time   Price     Address Gender
A3 B2 C3 D2  125.0  343.43         NaN    NaN
A1 B2 C3 D4  120.0   51.40  4 Brown St    NaN
```

or `time < 125` and no gender specified:

```
df[(df['time'] < 125) & df['Gender'].isna()]
```

Output:

```
              time  Price     Address Gender
A1 B1 C2 D6  123.0  23.43         NaN    NaN
A5 B3 C7 D1  124.0  14.63         NaN    NaN
A1 B2 C3 D4  120.0  51.40  4 Brown St    NaN
```

Comment: DANG! That almost answers all my questions! O_o. Two new questions: Question 5) I have a CSV file, that looks like the matrix. How do I read the CSV file? Question 6) I dont understand how to put several values into a cell. Say I want to put "Adress" and "time" and "Price" into a specific cell value. How do I do that, and how do I extract the different values? Should I use a dictionary or a list with three elements in that cell? Pandas is really wonderful! :)

Comment: @OrvarKorvar 5) pandas [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) should be tunable to read into a df like this

Comment: @OrvarKorvar 6) use separate cells, called 'Address', 'time' and 'Price'. You can then use `df.loc[(...index...)]` to read all three values as a Series, or `df.loc[(...index...), [...cells...]]` to just read specific cells (or even just one) into that series. See what I did to set both cells in Question 2 for an example of the syntax.

Comment: I dont understand. Can you give an example where you insert "Adress", "time", "price" and "Gender" into a cell using my matrix that I specified? I want to insert maybe 5-6 different text strings into one cell. What is the syntax to do that? And what is the syntax to extract for instance "Adress" from a cell?

Comment: @OrvarKorvar don't put all the data in one cell, use one cell each for "Adress", "time", "price" and "Gender". Then you would just use the notation that I used for question 2, or to insert all values (assuming the cells are in the order you specified) you could just (for example) use `df.loc[('A1','B1','C2','D6')] = [45, '16:02', 9.99, 'male']`

Comment: aha, so you basically insert a List into the cell? And then I can use ordinary List syntax to manipulate all the data in the cell? And, if I wanted I could instead insert a dictionary into each cell? That way I dont have to remember the ordering, I can instead extract the different data, using key words?

Comment: @OrvarKorvar no, there are 4 separate cells, but you are assigning them all at the same time from a list. It's the same as writing `df.loc[('A1','B1','C2','D6'), ['Address', 'time', 'Price', 'Gender']] = [45, '16:02', 9.99, 'male']`.

Comment: Note your question already has 2 separate cells, one for `time` and one for `Price`, we are just adding two more here for `Address` and `Gender`

Comment: I am not clear enough. I am trying to say that the original matrix does not have "adress" and "gender" columns. It has only 6 columns if you count them. I wonder if it is possible to add much more information in each cell. Say I want to add 10 different strings into each cell, "adress", "gender", "birthdate", "salary", etc etc etc. Could I put all these 10 strings into one list, and then insert that list into a cell? If so, how is that syntax to insert and extract each substring? If not possible to add more information into each cell, then I need to use several different matrices?

Comment: @OrvarKorvar I guess I'm not being clear enough either; I'm saying you should not "add much more information in each cell" but instead add a *new* cell for each extra piece of information. That will make searching and operating on your data *much* easier. and you can still have only one matrix. Please see my edit for examples.

Comment: Great edits! If I could upvote several times, I would. Thanx a lot! I think this answers all my questions. What I am actually trying to do, is to regularly scan CSV files, and then calculate the average price of all scanned CSV files. To do that, I need to sum all prices, and also have a counter how many prices I have added in a cell. Assume in one cell: all the prices up until now, sums to 100 and the counter says 5, it means the average price is 100/5=20 of all today's CSV files. That is why I need to add more information into each cell. Thanx! Your answers will be great for future reference

Comment: @OrvarKorvar I'm glad the edits help explain in a way that worked for you. It's been an interesting question, and I'm glad I could help.